# Redux-Thunk Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, thunk

I have a songbook app with firebase as a backend and struggling with an
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Action creator

```
export const createAction = (type, payload) => ({ type, payload });
```

songs.action.js

```
import { getSongsAndDocuments } from '../../utils/firebase/firebase.utils';

export const fetchSongsStart = () => {
    createAction(SONGS_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_SONGS_START);
};

export const fetchSongsSuccess = songs => {
    createAction(SONGS_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_SONGS_SUCCESS, songs)
};

export const fetchSongsFailed = error => {
    createAction(SONGS_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_SONGS_FAILED, error);
};

export const fetchSongsAsync = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchSongsStart());

        try {
            const songs = await getSongsAndDocuments();
            dispatch(fetchSongsSuccess(songs));
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(fetchSongsFailed(error));
        }
    };
};
```

Songbook.jsx

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchSongsAsync());
    }, []);
```

store.js

```
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { rootReducer } from './root-reducer';

const middleWares = [thunk];

const composeEnhancer =
    (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && window && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
    compose;

const composedEnhancers = composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(...middleWares));

export const store = createStore(rootReducer, undefined, composedEnhancers);
```

Comment: in your action creator functions use `return createAction(SONGS_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_SONGS_START);` notice the `return`.

Comment: hey Alan... thank you very much for your answer! you were right about it. thanks!
also, how can I mark your comment as a correct answer?? :P

Comment: Apart from that, you are writing a very outdated style of Redux there - in modern Redux you would not write action creators or switch..case reducers and createStore/applyMiddleware/compose etc. are abstracted into `configureStore`. Please give https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the result of calling `createAction` function in your action creator functions that is:

```
return createAction(SONGS_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_SONGS_START);
```

instead of:

```
createAction(SONGS_ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_SONGS_START);
```